# Unable to select all the existing text and paste new text in ckeditor using IE11

Tags: ckeditor, internet-explorer-11

I am using `ckeditor 3.4.1`. I am not able to select all the existing text and paste new text in ckeditor tool box using `Internet Explorer 11`.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very antique version of CKEditor that was [released 6 years ago](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-3.4.1-released) when Internet Explorer 8 was the new thing :) Internet Explorer 11 compatibility was introduced in [CKEditor 4.3](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.3-Released), so if you expect these two tools to work, you need to upgrade your CKEditor. The latest editor is the greatest editor, and by skipping upgrades you are missing out on a great deal of new features as well as bug fixes (including security patches!).